# GIS feature labeling and removal of None or Empty fields

Tags: python

A working label expression for ArcGIS 10.3. I was using dictionary key:values but sometimes the keys would have the same value so my items were 'disappearing' out of the dictionary. Now I use this simple counter to group my values from a list (0,1) (2,3) (4,5). I think the `if` functions might be able to be combined, as well as perhaps setting the `list[i*2]` and `list[(i*2)+1]` to variables instead of repeating them 3 times.

```
def FindLabel ( [Elevation] , [Out_Elev] , [Out_Loc] , [In1_Elev] , [In1_Loc] , [In2_Elev] , [In2_Loc] , [In3_Elev] , [In3_Loc]  ):
  list = [Out_Elev],[Out_Loc],[In1_Elev],[In1_Loc],[In2_Elev],[In2_Loc],[In3_Elev],[In3_Loc]
  x = [Elevation] + " Top"
  for i in range(len(list)/2): 
    if list[i*2] is not None:
      if list[i*2].strip() != "":
       if list[(i*2)+1] is not None:
         if list[(i*2)+1].strip() !="":
           x = x  + "\n" + "(" + str(list[i*2]) + ": " + str(list[(i*2)+1]) + ")"
  return x
```

Comment: Wait, is this even valid syntax? It doesn't run on my machine, and unless one of the newer 3.x versions support it (to my shame, I'm not familiar enough with them) this is broken code.

Comment: perhaps I should have mentioned it is a label expression for ArcGIS desktop. The code does work. It labels a manhole and any invert with direction (In1_Loc) and elevation.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consolidate the body of this quite a bit.  First, I'd make `list[i*2]` and `list[i*2+1]` into variables, probably

```
first_element = list[i*2]
second_element = list[i*2+1]
```

Then you can clean up the if statements as well

```
if first_element and first_element.strip() and second_element and second_element.strip():
```

However, that makes it clear that what you're doing is the same for both.  I'd write a little helper function

```
def validate_element(element):
    return element and element.strip()

if validate_element(first_element) and validate_element(second_element):
```

You should also use a format string and `string.join` instead of concatenation

```
lines = ["{} Top".format([Elevation]]

for i in range(len(list)/2):
    first_element = list[i*2]
    second_element = list[i*2+1]
    if validate_element(first_element) and validate_element(second_element):
        lines.append("({}:{})".format(first_element, second_element))

return '\n'.join(lines)
```

You could probably turn this into a list comprehension if you wanted to, but that probably isn't worth the effort and ugliness that would ensue.

Your names in general are pretty bad - `list` is especially horrific because you're now masking a builtin function - you can no longer use the `list` constructor.  Try to use descriptive names to actually describe what the values represent.